# How to evenly space out y ticks for tikzpicture graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to achieve the following spread of ticks on my latex graph:

[image]

Even though the difference between each y tick is increasing the spacing remains constant. How can I reflect this on a latex graph. Here is my code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={CPU-DRAM Gap},
    xlabel={Year},
    ylabel={Clock frequency (Hz)},
    xmin=1980, xmax=2000,
    ymin=1, ymax=1000,
    xtick={1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000},
    ytick={1,10,100,1000},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,]

\addplot[
    color=blue,]
    coordinates {
    (1980,1)(1981,2)(1982,3)(1983,4)(1984,5)(1985,6)(1986,7)(1987,8)(1988,9)(1989,13)(1990,20)(1991,40)(1992,60)(1993,80)(1994,100)(1995,150)(1996,200)(1997,400)(1998,600)(1999,800)(2000,1000)};

\addplot[
    color=red,]
    coordinates {
    (1980,1)(1981,1.2)(1982,1.5)(1983,1.8)(1984,2.1)(1985,2.4)(1986,2.7)(1987,3)(1988,3.3)(1989,3.6)(1990,3.9)(1991,4.2)(1992,4.5)(1993,4.8)(1994,5.1)(1995,5.4)(1996,5.7)(1997,6)(1998,6.3)(1999,6.6)(2000,6.9)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The current output is the following

[image]

How do I space the y ticks evenly on my latex graph as shown on the initial graph?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you mean a logarithmic axis?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: instead `begin{axis} ... `end{axis}` try `\begin{semilogyaxis} ... \end{semilogyaxis}`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
every axis plot post/.append style={
mark=square*, mark color = green}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
    title={CPU-DRAM Gap},
    xlabel={Year},
    ylabel={Clock frequency (Hz)},
    xmin=1980, xmax=2000,
    ymin=1, ymax=1000,
    xtick=data,
    ytick={1,10,100,1000},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    yminorticks=false,
    grid style=dashed,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east},
    x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,-.2)},anchor=north},
    height = 6cm,
    width = 14cm,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    axis line style={-|}]

\addplot[mark options={fill=red}]
    coordinates {
    (1980,1)(1981,2)(1982,3)(1983,4)(1984,5)(1985,6)(1986,7)(1987,8)(1988,9)(1989,13)(1990,20)(1991,40)(1992,60)(1993,80)(1994,100)(1995,150)(1996,200)(1997,400)(1998,600)(1999,800)(2000,1000)};

\addplot[mark options={fill=green}]
    coordinates {
    (1980,1)(1981,1.2)(1982,1.5)(1983,1.8)(1984,2.1)(1985,2.4)(1986,2.7)(1987,3)(1988,3.3)(1989,3.6)(1990,3.9)(1991,4.2)(1992,4.5)(1993,4.8)(1994,5.1)(1995,5.4)(1996,5.7)(1997,6)(1998,6.3)(1999,6.6)(2000,6.9)};

\legend{CPU, DRAM}

\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Also you should have a look at your data, because I think you didnt quite got the right numbers out of your original graph. Hence the waves.

Comment: I would just add `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/set thousands separator={}}` to get rid of the `,` in the years.

Comment: @Mike good point. Will do :)